# Session message not displayed while other session are working

Tags: php, session, mysqli, session-variables

I have a button add update and delete, the add button and update work fine and displays my Session message and msg_type accordingly, however the when I click on the delete button I wont get any Session message even though the record is deleted. All my add, update and delete files are from the same file called authController, where I call a session_start function at the beginning of the file.

Here in my PHP files I call the function to display session message

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
<div class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?>">
   <?php
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
   ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Here is my delete function in my authController.php;

```
    if(isset($_POST['delete_employee'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
        $role = $_POST['role'];
        $competency = $_POST['competency'];
        
        $key = $_POST['keyToDelete'];

        //check if records exists to delete or not
        $sql= "DELETE FROM employees WHERE id='$key'";
        $result= mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        if($result) {
            //send flash messages
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Employee record Deleted !";
            $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
            header("Location: Employee.php");
        } 
    }

    if(isset($_POST['add_job'])) {

        $job_name = $_POST['job_name'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $competency = $_POST['competency'];
        $competent=implode(',',$competency);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO job (`job_name`, `department`, `competency`) VALUES ('$job_name', '$department', '$competent')";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        if($result) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Job Role succesfully added !";
            $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";
            header("Location: Job.php");
        }
    }
```

Also, when I call another add function which is in another page the record is successfully added but no Session message is displayed. Can someone tell me where I made a mistake please, because I cant find the error and everything seems to be working except for the session message which is not displaying.

Comment: Did you start the session in both files?

Comment: yes i have started session

Comment: No message shown, but have you confirmed that the `<div>` for message is not there as well?